# Can asp.net core 3.1 partialview contain jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am very new to asp.net core razor development. Can a asp.net core 3.1 partialview contain jQuery code. I can get normal JavaScript to work inside a partial view but cannot get jQuery to work in the partial view. The main page that references the partialview can catch the onchange event. Just want to know what is the best practice with regards to jQuery script and partialviews

```
@model IndexModel

<script type="text/javascript">

    alert("hello mark")

    $("#ddlPartnersPartial").change(function () {
        alert("ddlPartnersPartial")
    });
</script>

<form method="post">
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Discount Status</div>
            <div class="col">PMN</div>
            <div class="col">ContractToDate</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select asp-for="SelectedStatusPartner" asp-items="Model.Partners" id="ddlPartnersPartial">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That version of jQuery is positively _ancient_, and [you probably don't need to load it anyway](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: At any rate, you'd need to load jQuery _before_ you try running it. You can't call library methods if the library isn't present. You're probably seeing a console error.

Comment: If you're going to be using jquery , you're most likely to be using it in other places as well. Include it in a master layout. Your are also not taking advantage of `$(document).ready()` , the element does not yet exist in the DOM when you are trying to reference it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you call these partialview?  By using ajax or else?